# drupal breadcrumb not showing for content item

Tags: drupal

I have a drupal application which does not have/need any Menu items within it. I am using the Taxonomy Submenu module to navigate through contents. I have the content structured as follows.

Taxonomy->terms->subterms->subterms->...->content

On the homepage it will list all the first level terms using the Taxonomy submenu module, clicking on the main menu will populate submenus and finally towards the end it will show a particular content.

Each time when we reach on a sub term the breadcrumb is populating and showing correctly, but when I reach in content it does not show any breadcrumb.

Summary:
http://localhost/mydrupapp/taxonomy/term/134 showing breadcrumb and
http://localhost/mydrupapp/node/29 not showing breadcrumb.
The fact is the content 29 is created under the term 134.
Point to note
The site does not have or need any menu items.

I want to display breadcrumb for the content pages based on the taxonomy of that particular content. If a content 'Hello World' is added under the taxonomy term 'General' then when I view the page 'Hello World' I need the breadcrumb 'Home->General->Hello World'

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Taxonomy breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_breadcrumb) module and see if it works.
For my site too it worked, without it, it wasn't correctly showing path.

Comment: sorry I missed out one important note. I am using Drupal 7.  The module Taxonomy breadcrumb does not support drupal 7.  Thanks for your comment and time.  I will try to develop from this piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

in drupal 7 taxonomy breadcrumb settings are include
please go to config>custombreadcrumbsettings set there taxonomy settings,
it is work for me hope also will work for you.